# Поиск и замена строки

Tags: javascript

На странице есть `n` количество уникальных элементов со значением 3 333.
Необходимо заменить значение на произвольное, как это сделать ?

Пример:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var source = document.body.innerHTML;
    var str_before = '−3&nbsp;333';
    var str_after = '123';
    var changed = source.replace(str_before, str_after);
    console.log(changed);
});
```

```html
<span class="1Jk62" data-qa-type="uikit">−3&nbsp;333<span class="2ldL6">,00</span></span>
```

Comment: твой код уже находит и меняет. Чем он тебя не устраивает?

Comment: @Grundy, он меняет только первый встречный. Я добавил ответ с регуляркой и без реализацию его метода

Comment: @AzizUmarov, менять `innerHTML` - у body не очень решение

Comment: @Grundy Я показал как применять 2 метода для замены строки, а innerHtml идет из задачи. А то что вообще откуда может возникнуть такая задача это к Автору. Лично для меня не понятны источники таких задач и тем более такое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Способов несколько но можно и так.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var source = document.body.innerHTML;
  var str_before = '−3&nbsp;333';
  var str_after = '123';
  var changed = source.split(str_before).join(str_after);
  //alert(changed);

  document.body.innerHTML = changed;
});
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<span class="1Jk62" data-qa-type="uikit">
−3&nbsp;333
<span class="2ldL6">,00</span>
</span>
<span class="1Jk62" data-qa-type="uikit">
−3&nbsp;333
<span class="2ldL6">,00</span>
</span>
<span class="1Jk62" data-qa-type="uikit">
−3&nbsp;333
<span class="2ldL6">,00</span>
</span>
```

или так

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var source = document.body.innerHTML;
  var str_before = /−3&nbsp;333/g;
  var str_after = '123';
  var changed = source.replace(str_before, str_after);
  // alert(changed);
  document.body.innerHTML = changed;
});
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<span class="1Jk62" data-qa-type="uikit">
−3&nbsp;333
<span class="2ldL6">,00</span>
</span>
<span class="1Jk62" data-qa-type="uikit">
−3&nbsp;333
<span class="2ldL6">,00</span>
</span>
<span class="1Jk62" data-qa-type="uikit">
−3&nbsp;333
<span class="2ldL6">,00</span>
</span>
```